# Grails: NPE in Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, grails-2.0

I'm writing a unit test for my domain class but I get a NPE when I tried to run the following test:

```
def st

void setUp(){
    super.setUp()
    mockForConstraintsTests(Student)        
    st=new Student(firstName:"Feras",lastName:"Ahmad")


}

void testMinSize() {        
    st.firstName="J"
    assertFalse st.validate();              
}
```

I got the NPE on the first line of testMinSize method. what is wrong with that? I think setUp method is called before every test. Is this true?

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried adding debug points to see at what line you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @Mock(Student)

at the top of your Test class

Comment: what will @Mock do if I add it?

Comment: I see that you are getting error on calling setUp(). Just add @Before on the setUp() method and remove super.setUp() line.

Comment: Also make sure you have @TestFor annotation above the Test class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try the `@Before` annotation

```
@Before
void setUp(){
    super.setUp()
    print "I'm there"
    mockForConstraintsTests(Student)        
    st=new Student(firstName:"Feras",lastName:"Ahmad")
}
```

The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html) puts sometime the annotation, sometime not. Maybe it depends on the grails/JUnit version.

Comment: I got   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: student.domain.StudentTests.setUp() is applicable for argument types: ()